# Is this a gdb bug in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, gdb, coredump

I used gdb to attach a program, and then set a breakpoint in function engine::monAppendSystemInfo. When the breakpoint was hit, the gdb coredump(actually, it's my program crashed in engine::monAppendSystemInfo).This is not an inevitable problem. It has only appeared twice and cannot be reproduced.

Here is the compared assembly code of engine::monAppendSystemInfo.

The code below is disassembled from the coredump file:

```
Dump of assembler code for function engine::monAppendSystemInfo(bson::BSONObjBuilder&, unsigned int):
   0x00000000011188f1 <+0>:     push   %rbp
   0x00000000011188f2 <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x00000000011188f5 <+4>:     push   %r12
   0x00000000011188f7 <+6>:     push   %rbx
   0x00000000011188f8 <+7>:     sub    $0xb20,%rsp
   0x00000000011188ff <+14>:    mov    %rdi,-0xa98(%rbp)
   0x0000000001118906 <+21>:    mov    %esi,-0xa9c(%rbp)
   0x000000000111890c <+27>:    int3                      // strange point
=> 0x000000000111890d <+28>:    mov    0x28,%rax          // crash for accessing 0x28
   0x0000000001118915 <+36>:    mov    %rax,-0x18(%rbp)
```

The code below is disassembled from normal gdb, and the program can continue to run:

```
Dump of assembler code for function engine::monAppendSystemInfo(bson::BSONObjBuilder&, unsigned int):
   0x00000000011188f1 <+0>:     push   %rbp
   0x00000000011188f2 <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x00000000011188f5 <+4>:     push   %r12
   0x00000000011188f7 <+6>:     push   %rbx
   0x00000000011188f8 <+7>:     sub    $0xb20,%rsp
   0x00000000011188ff <+14>:    mov    %rdi,-0xa98(%rbp)
   0x0000000001118906 <+21>:    mov    %esi,-0xa9c(%rbp)
=> 0x000000000111890c <+27>:    mov    %fs:0x28,%rax     // "%fs:0x28" was changed to "0x28" in above
   0x0000000001118915 <+36>:    mov    %rax,-0x18(%rbp)
```

My linux is: ubuntu16.04.4 LTS, and the enviroment is as below:

```
root@lyysdbserver1:~# g++ --version  
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) 5.4.0 20160609  
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

root@lyysdbserver1:~# gdb --version  
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.11.1-0ubuntu1~16.5) 7.11.1  
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Why "%fs:0x28" was changed to "0x28"? Is this a gdb bug ?

Comment: Undefined behaviour? Please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you're looking of a coredump of your program when GDB had already set a breakpoint. `int 3` is how GDB sets a breakpoint. When you resume, the `int 3` instruction should be replaced by the original byte.

Look how the machine code compares for these two instruction sequences:

```
mov %fs:0x28,%rax;    64 48 8b 04 25 28 00 00 00
int 3; mov 0x28,%rax; cc 48 8b 04 25 28 00 00 00
```